# How to markup a legal permission with a linked digital copy by using the "Occupation" type?

Tags: schema.org

I'm just creating the schema code for my aboutme-page, where I introduce myself and my professions. I'm an alternative healer. `Person` is (and should remain, if possible) the top-level-item. On the aboutme-page I have referenced my legal state permission by linking to a digital copy on my site (.jpg).

The code I have created so far:

```json
"@type": "Person",
"hasOccupation": {
  "@type": "Occupation",
  "name": "alternative healer", 
  "educationRequirements": {
    "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
    "credentialCategory": "state permission for alternative healers" 
    "recognizedBy": { 
      "@type": "GovernmentOrganization", 
      "name": "(name of government agency)"
      },
    "license": "(Wordpress-URL of state permission as .jpg)"
    }
   }
  }
```

Is this code correct regarding the last property `license`, which should connect to the digital copy as an linked .jpg? Is it understandable this way for search engines that this digital copy is my concrete state permission and not any sample?

Would it be better to use `url` or `image` as understandable connection to my permission, instead of `license`? Or `DigitalDocument`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`license` property](https://schema.org/license) gives the license (e.g., as in [copyright license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_copyright_license)) that applies to the creative work. It’s not for any kind of thing that gets called *license*.

Your `EducationalOccupationalCredential` represents the legal state permission license; if you provide a `license` property, it would be for giving the license (e.g., copyright) of the license (legal state permission).

To provide the digital file, you can use one (or several) of these ways:

- [`associatedMedia`](https://schema.org/associatedMedia)/[`encoding`](https://schema.org/encoding) - this allows you to provide metadata about the file
- [`image`](https://schema.org/image) - can be just the URL, or also an object that allows you to provide metadata about the file
- [`url`](https://schema.org/url) - this doesn’t allow you to provide metadata about the file

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood license and its description "A license document that applies to this content". Thanks for clearing this. Btw, if you want correct it: licen**c**e at the end of my post. The whole occupation-code is correct?

Comment: @Martinus33: You can correct it yourself (just click "edit"). Seems to be fine; you could ask on [codereview.se] for a full review of your JSON-LD (I’m not 100 % sure if this is on-topic there, but I think there were a few questions like that in the past).

Comment: Would it be an equivalent and also correct solution for my purpose of saying "this person has a legal permission which is linked as .jpg" if I would code it as Person --> subjectOf --> EducationalOccupationalCredential (tell me if i should ask a new question)

Comment: @Martinus33: I would say it’s not fitting. While the person is, in some sense, the subject of the credential, it’s not *the* subject (what would typically be understood under this). But I also wouldn’t say that it’s wrong to use it.

Comment: I understand. SubjectOf has a further disadvantage for my case: occupation is missing, where I could add a reference to Wikipedia (describing the profession) via sameAs. A further idea came in my mind: action. Does Person --> (any fitting) action --> ...result EducationalOccupationalCredential express a person who made/achieved a credential or a person who is subject of the action (i.e. an object)?

Comment: @Martinus33: I guess `Action` (e.g., `AchieveAction`) could work. The `agent` would be the `Person`, the `object` would be the `EducationalOccupationalCredential`. But you can’t use this with `Person` as top-level item, unless you use `@reverse` -- but, depending on your reason why you want `Person` as top-level item, this might not be what you want.

Comment: Yeah, for Google I'd prefer the top-level-item Person for a Person-page. Action is a very useful schema element, but you always have to use the action itsself or the object as leading item type? Then followed by the subject (agent). Due to the nature of action-schema, the active subject cannot be the leading item type, right? The order in code is not possible as "subject-predicate-object" which we know from sentence syntax, learned at school?

Comment: @Martinus33: You can have this order in the code by using `@reverse`, if that’s all you care about. However, a consumer would "resolve" those `@reverse` statements, and a different item might become the top-level item. -- Semantically, it doesn’t matter which items are on the top-level -- they aren’t more significant or something like that (a "bad" consumer might assume something else, though).

Comment: Google rules want one main object per page, reflected by the top-level-item, but there is another reason against reverse: Almost nobody knows and uses it, neither www nor schema.org itsself give me solid information about it. Very uncertain IMHO, how SE will deal with it. One last idea may work too: I could use action on aboutPage, but it's not as relevant and fitting as Person for my case, isn't it (page, not person itsself...)? Thanks for your patience and competence.